# How to stop angular from passing attributes to replaced element in custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom angular directive that uses replace: true.  When I do that, I noticed all attributes in my custom tag are transferred to the top-level element in my directive's template.  Is there a way to stop it from doing that?

```
<custom someAttr="someVal"></custom>
```

When replaced, the code looks like this...

```
<div class="custom" someAttr="someVal"></div>
```

I want it to just be...

```
<div class="custom"></div>
```

But still be able to access someAttr's value in my scope...

```
.directive('custom', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      someAttr: '@'
    },
    template: '<div class="custom">{{someAttr}}</div>'
  }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could remove the isolated scope.

Comment: I removed the isolated scope but it still transfers the attributes to the top element.

Comment: If you have replace true why are you adding attributes?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answers in this question might help:

[How to prevent duplicated attributes in angular directive when replace=true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075750/how-to-prevent-duplicated-attributes-in-angular-directive-when-replace-true)

Here's a suggestion from @user2943490:

```
.directive('foo', function() {
  return {
    // ..
    compile: compile
    // ..
  };

  function compile(tElement, tAttrs) {
    // destination element you want to manipulate attrs on
    var destEl = tElement.find(...);

    angular.forEach(tAttrs, function (value, key) {
      manipulateAttr(tElement, destEl, key);
    })

    var postLinkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {
      // your link function
      // ...
    }

    return postLinkFn;
  }

  function manipulateAttr(src, dest, attrName) {
    // do your manipulation
    // ...
  }
})
```

And here's another approach from @Enzey:

```
.directive('foo', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: function(element, attrs) {
            var template = '<div bar="{{bar}}" baz="baz"></div>';
            template = angular.element(template);
            Object.keys(attrs.$attr).forEach(function(attr) {\
                // Remove all attributes on the element from the template before returning it.
                template.removeAttr(attrs.$attr[attr]);
            });
            return template;
        },
        scope: {
          bar: '@'
        }
    };
})
```