# How to prevent duplicated attributes in angular directive when replace=true

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've found that angular directives that specify `replace: true` will copy attributes from the directive usage into the output rendered by the template. If the template contains the same attribute, both the template attribute value and the directive attribute value will be combined together in the final output.

Directive usage:

```
<foo bar="one" baz="two"></foo>
```

Directive:

```
.directive('foo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div bar="{{bar}}" baz="baz"></div>',
    scope: {
      bar: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl) {
      scope.bar = scope.bar || 'bar';
    }
  };
})
```

Output:

```
<div bar="one " baz="two baz" class="ng-isolate-scope"></div>
```

The space in `bar="one "` is causing problems, as is multiple values in `baz`. Is there a way to alter this behavior? I realized I could use non-conflicting attributes in my directive and have both the template attributes and the non-conflicting attributes in the output. But I'd like to be able to use the same attribute names, and control the output of the template better.

I suppose I could use a `link` method with `element.removeAttr()` and `element.attr()`. It just seems like there should be a better solution.

Lastly, I realize there is talk of deprecating `remove: true`, but there are valid reasons for keeping it. In my case, I need it for directives that generate SVG tags using transclusion. See here for details:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/eec6394a342fb92fba5270eee11c83f1d895e9fb

Comment: This is a design conflict. `replace` should only be used with simple `<div>` and no attributes. If you have any need for the attributes, they should be passed to directive not to the element being replaced.

Comment: @DaveAlperovich Can you elaborate on what you mean, any docs or links that describe your concern in more depth? I'd like to pass attributes in the element so that isolate scope can be set, but I don't wan those attributes to be output. Only the attributes in the template should be output. I have to use `replace` since I'm working with SVG tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't some nice declarative way to tell Angular how `x` attribute should be merged or manipulated when transplanted into templates.

Angular actually does a straight copy of attributes from the source to the destination element (with a few exceptions) and merges attribute values. You can see this behaviour in the [`mergeTemplateAttributes`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/9b3d9656a69a931f4fcd321cedf837661e1e5785/src/ng/compile.js#L2104) function of the Angular compiler.

Since you can't change that behaviour, you can get some control over attributes and their values with the `compile` or `link` properties of the directive definition. It most likely makes more sense for you to do attribute manipulation in the compile phase rather than the link phase, since you want these attributes to be "ready" by the time any link functions run.

You can do something like this:

```
.directive('foo', function() {
  return {
    // ..
    compile: compile
    // ..
  };

  function compile(tElement, tAttrs) {
    // destination element you want to manipulate attrs on
    var destEl = tElement.find(...);

    angular.forEach(tAttrs, function (value, key) {
      manipulateAttr(tElement, destEl, key);
    })

    var postLinkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {
      // your link function
      // ...
    }

    return postLinkFn;
  }

  function manipulateAttr(src, dest, attrName) {
    // do your manipulation
    // ...
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming that angular has no declarative way to do what I'd like as well as sharing a suggested solution. I was hoping to avoid using a compile function, but perhaps it is best for my needs.

Answer (score 3):

It would be helpful to know how you expect the values to be merged. Does the template take priority, the element, or is some kind of merge needed?

Lacking that I can only make an assumption, the below code assumes you want to remove attributes from the template that exist on the element.

```
.directive('foo', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: function(element, attrs) {
            var template = '<div bar="{{bar}}" baz="baz"></div>';
            template = angular.element(template);
            Object.keys(attrs.$attr).forEach(function(attr) {\
                // Remove all attributes on the element from the template before returning it.
                template.removeAttr(attrs.$attr[attr]);
            });
            return template;
        },
        scope: {
          bar: '@'
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: I want the attributes in the element to be passed to the directive to be used to set isolate scopes, but I do not want those attributes to be included in the output. Only the attributes in the template should be output. Thanks for your solution idea, I think it could be useful!