# Transfer attributes from one directive to another

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-directive, kendo-dropdown

I have directive `foo` that I want to use on another directive `dropdown`. The problem is that the `dropdown` directive is using yet another directive called `kendo-drop-down-list` in the template.

I want to be able to write

```
<dropdown foo>
```

And the result should be

```
<select data-kendo-drop-down-list options='dropdownOptions' data-ng-model='selected' foo="bar"></select>
```

Problem is that `foo` is optional, meaning that the directive will be used both like `<dropdown>` and `<dropdown foo="bar">`.

How do I transfer the attributes? Or am I doing something wrong since I ended up with this problem?

**Directive**

```
app.directive('dropdown', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        scope: {
            selected: "=ngModel",
        },
        template: "<select data-kendo-drop-down-list data-k-options='dropdownOptions' data-ng-model='selected'></select>",
        controller: [
            '$scope', function($scope) {                
                $scope.dropdownOptions = {
                    dataSource: {
                        type: "odata-v4",
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: "odata/Products",
                                dataType: "json",
                            }
                        },
                        serverFiltering: true,
                    }
                };
            }
        ]
    };
);
```

Comment: I don't really get your problem. If you are using `<dropdown foo="bar">` you can simply pass your data to your directive into your scope via e.g. `data: '=foo'`

Comment: `foo` needs to be put in the template of the `dropdown` directive

Comment: ah I see, so you want to pass data from your controller to a directive and into another directive?

Comment: Yeah that sounds about right :) But I want the transfer logic to be somewhat generic so that I'm forced to alter it if I someday rename or add a directive to the list

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out. Inspired by this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27261632/1220627

```
app.directive('dropdown', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        scope: {
            selected: "=ngModel",
        },
        template: function(element, attrs) {
            var templateHtml = "<select data-kendo-drop-down-list data-k-options='dropdownOptions' data-ng-model='selected'></select>";
            var templateElement = angular.element(templateHtml);

            _.pairs(attrs.$attr).forEach(function (pair) {
                var attributeName = pair[0];
                var attributeNameActual = pair[1];
                // ignore attribute(s) from scope
                if (attributeName === "ngModel")
                    return;

                var attributeValue = attrs[attributeName];
                templateElement.attr(attributeNameActual, attributeValue);
            });

            return templateElement;
        },
        controller: [
            '$scope', function($scope) {                
                $scope.dropdownOptions = {
                    dataSource: {
                        type: "odata-v4",
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: "odata/Products",
                                dataType: "json",
                            }
                        },
                        serverFiltering: true,
                    }
                };
            }
        ]
    };
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a controller's `$scope` variable from `directiveA` to `directiveB` like this:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('directiveA', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<directive-b foo="data"></directive-b>',
        scope: {
            data: '='
        }
    }
});

myApp.directive('directiveB', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '{{data}} I am Directive B!',
        scope: {
            data: '=foo'
        }
    }
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = 'Hi there!';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <directive-a data="foo"></directive-a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But it looks like I didn't explain the problem proper. It shouldn't just transfer the value but both attribute and value so that the tag in the template would trigger the `foo` directive